# Pyspark: How to create a flag for the first time a variable is seen

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a set of variables that that a timestamp and a session. How would I make a New Session Indicator that is 1 for the first time a session is seen and 0 for every instance of that session thereafterwards. For instance...

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ("a", "44", "2018-01-08 09:01:01.085193"),
        ("a", "44", "2018-01-08 09:01:01.086280"),
        ("a", "44", "2018-01-08 09:01:01.087681"),
        ("a", "95", "2018-01-15 12:01:01.544710"),
        ("a", "95", "2018-01-15 13:01:01.545991"),
], ["person_id", "session_id", "timestamp"])

df = df.withColumn('unix_ts',F.unix_timestamp(df.timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
df = df.withColumn("DayOfWeek",F.date_format(df.timestamp, 'EEEE'))
df.show()
```

Yields

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+
|person_id|session_id|           timestamp|   unix_ts|DayOfWeek|
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|
|        a|        95|2018-01-15 12:01:...|1516039261|   Monday|
|        a|        95|2018-01-15 13:01:...|1516042861|   Monday|
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+
```

I want to have add a column giving this output:

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+----------+
|person_id|session_id|           timestamp|   unix_ts|DayOfWeek| FirstInd |   
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+----------+
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|     1    |
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|     0    |
|        a|        44|2018-01-08 09:01:...|1515423661|   Monday|     0    |
|        a|        95|2018-01-15 12:01:...|1516039261|   Monday|     1    |
|        a|        95|2018-01-15 13:01:...|1516042861|   Monday|     0    |
+---------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Hint: `row_number()` and using `pyspark.sql.window` objects over `session_id`

Comment: Got it! df = df.withColumn("rowNum",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('person_id','session_id').orderBy("unix_ts")))
At least, this is sufficient for me. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MicahPearce can you post that as a solution? It may be useful for others who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. While it technically isn't a flag, it you do know exactly which row is row number 1.
    df.withColumn("rowNum",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('person_id','session_id').orderBy("unix_ts")))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('person_id','session_id').orderBy("unix_ts")   
df = df.withColumn("FirstInd",F.when(F.row_number().over(window) == 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```